# How to toggle javascript panel on the right side of website with a Bootstrap grid?

Tags: javascript, css, django, twitter-bootstrap, grid

I want to imitate the shopping bag function of http://www.chaldal.com You will see a small box on the right that shows the summary, however if you click on it, it expands and takes a permanent place on the right two columns. I have created six columns with Bootstrap for the item list. I can create the small box with a position absolute I guess. How can I create the expanded shopping bag that takes the right two columns to display and doesn't go away even if I browse the website. Also, I used the following code for displaying items in 6 columns.

```
<div id="product-list" class="row">
    {% for item in items %}
        <div class="col-sm-2">
            <h5 class="text-center">{{ item.name }}</h5>
            {% widthratio item.height item.width 150 as height %}
            {% if item.image %}
                <img src="/{{ item.image }}" height="{{ height }}" width="150"/>
            {% else %}
                <img src="{% static 'default_images/default_medicine.jpg' %}" width="150"/>
            {% endif %}
            Tk. {{ item.mrp }} / {{ item.unit }}
        </div>
        {% if forloop.counter|divisibleby:6 %}
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
    </div>
```

How can I change it to four columns when the shopping bag toggles on? The divisible by number has to change also.

Answer (score 0):

In chaldal.com, what happens is that when you click on the small button, it pushes all the container content with a padding of 300px, so one way to getting your columns in bootstrap to a smaller width, is to change the containers width percentage. In bootstrap if you set panels to col-lg-6, when reaching devices for that screen resolution it will just change its width. So for example for 6 columns it will be 50% width, if you want to change that width column your best show is to add another class at the end of the column classes like this:

```
<div class="col-sm-2 newClass"></div>
```

And in your javascript you could assign a padding, width, fixed right positioning, or anything you want to change the class that already have those columns layout.

Hope this helps.